# saving rqt plot data as csv

Tags: rqt, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ros a topic `/uav1/aerodynamics/wrench` having multiple param. Such as  fore:x,y,z and torque:x,y,z data. I want to plot it `rqr_plot` and save the simulation data as CSV file. How can I do that

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414601/saving-rqt-plot-data-as-csv/) by [Mubashir alam](https://answers.ros.org/users/85455/mubashir-alam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2023-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wouldn't try to save it from rqt_plots, save it into a rosbag and then you can convert it into a csv (I think I used [this library before](https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/rosbag_to_csv)).

---

Originally posted by [sreed23](https://answers.ros.org/users/142993/sreed23/) with karma: 26 on 2023-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1